# No Such Module Alamofire in Xcode 8 and Swift 3

Tags: xcode, swift3, xcode8, alamofire

> No such module Alamofire

I tried importing Alamofire after I installed it from cocoapods. I also tried setting *Build Active Architecture Only* to NO. and then building the project and importing Alamofire. Even then it says 'no such module'.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1- Make sure that you are using the latest version of CocoaPods.

> To update CocoaPods with the latest version, open Terminal and use the
>   following command:
>  `$ sudo gem install cocoapods`

2- In your project settings -> Select the target -> Build Settings -> Framework Search Paths ->
Add `"$PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/Alamofire"` to the list of paths.